# Detect if there is Video <tag> inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

hey i got Multi iframe embeds each one have a video or source from site's like mega.nz - gdrive -jwplayer- and other have direct video link .mp4
is there any way to alawys detect iframe video source and return video.currentTime

this is my code but the issue with it there is a lot of issue's and not detecting all embeds

```
var video;
function Check(){
var monitor = setInterval(function(){
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
    const iframes = document.getElementById("mainly")
    const iframeDoc = iframes.contentDocument || iframes.contentWindow.document;
    video = iframeDoc.querySelector('video')

    }
}, 1000);
}
```

the iframe contain onload=Check() because i have another script to load diffrent src for the iframe so it will load again each time embed server selected i think
**Note: Sorry for my bad English**

Answer (score 0):

Their is no legit way to do this.